# How to return int,string and json of data in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to return a number, a string, and a json from the data in output of an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have this class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Customer(int _id, string _name)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

And my API method is:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("myAPI")]
public IActionResult myAPI()
{
    List<Customer> listName = new List<Customer>();
    listName.Add(new Customer(1, "name1"));
    listName.Add(new Customer(2, "name2"));
    listName.Add(new Customer(3, "name3"));

    int codeResult = 222;
    string message = "mymessage";

    return //how to return codeResult,message, Json(listName)
}
```

I expect the output to be as below

```
{
    codeResult: 222,
    message: "mymessage",
    data: [
             { "id": 1, "name": "name1" }...
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can return an anonymous object. But using a ViewModel a better practice.

Comment: Change return type from `IActionResult` to `JsonResult` (though this isn't really necessary). Return via call to `Json`: ~ `return Json(new { codeResult = codeResult , message = message , names = listName ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("myAPI")]
    public IActionResult myAPI()
    {
        List<Customer> listName = new List<Customer>();
        listName.Add(new Customer(1, "name1"));
        listName.Add(new Customer(2, "name2"));
        listName.Add(new Customer(3, "name3"));

        int codeResult = 222;
        string message = "mymessage";
        return Ok(new { codeResult = codeResult, message = message, data = listName});
    }
```

This is the result:

[image]